# Can I write a stand alone python script using gimp commands?

Tags: python, image-processing, gimp

I know you can write `python` scripts for `GIMP` and then through `GIMP` you can use these scripts as plug-ins but what I'm trying to achieve is to use `GIMP's functions` through `Python` as if you would use `PIL` or `scikit-image` functions through `Python`.I don't want to disturb my program user to actually download `Gimp` only to execute the one function I need from it.

Can I do such a thing ??? or I'm going too far?
If no, what is the best alternative thing I can do to force `Gimp` does the work undercover without disturbing the program user.in this case I think I would be forced to install `GIMP` within the installation process which is something I hate.

Update:-
(1) considering `libgimp` after googling I  found this [discussion](http://gimp.1065349.n5.nabble.com/libGimp-td17666.html).in brief words > " `libgimp` is just used to allow the `GIMP core` and it's plug-ins to communicate" so it doesn't work as I hope.
(2) I thought of accessing the `GIMP` code and deleting all unnecessary functions I don't need and keep the only function I'm gonna use,that would be a one function GIMP.Do you think I should do something like that?

**Update**:-
Yes the problem was solved but I'm still interested in using `GIMP` as a library by any means even if it was undercover as *Marawan* has suggested.Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: what os do u want to distribute to. win, linux or mac

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh Basically windows.The program should work under any platform anyway!!Does it make a diff??I mean why you ask??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [portable gimp](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable): this would allow you to have gimp be shipped with your program with no additional installation required by the user. You could then have functions in your python library run gimp operations using gimp's python scripting feature. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662676/writing-a-gimp-python-script/12663785#12663785) for an example doing this.

In the above example every call to the `flip` function will spawn a new gimp process and wait for it to finish executing. This can of course be slow. There are two strategies to improve the speed:

1. Reduce gimp startup time [using command line options that reduce startup time](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html)
2. Start one gimp process at program startup. Leave it running and communicate with it using some inter-process communication technique, and send it instructions whenever you want it to execute an operation.

Comment: +1 It worked but it takes so much time to execute the flip function you provided.Do u know why?Thanks

Comment: Good to hear it works. Could you time whole long it takes to call the function, i'm curious how slow it is. I'll update the answer with ways to speedup performance

Comment: almost 40 seconds elapsed since the first call till the GIMP output."I used `time.clock()` function.Mr Marwan do you think I'm going too far if I thought of deleting most of the GIMP functionality as I'm only interested in the *sharpen* filter.Thanks

Comment: well it shouldnt take that long. shouldnt be more then 5 seconds or so. im on vacation now, ill be back at my pc in a few days. ill give u more updates then

Comment: waiting for your help.have a nice vacation

Answer (score 2):

If GIMP is installed, you could try [batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). Another alternative is [to use gimp-fu](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?84073-Gimp-Python-batch-how-to).

Obviously, you cannot use GIMP if you don't have it installed. :-)

**EDIT**:

> I thought of accessing the GIMP code and deleting all unnecessary functions I don't need and keep the only function I'm gonna use,that would be a one function GIMP.

That seems overly ambitious. The GIMP codebase is large and complicated.

As an alternative for image manipulation, you might have a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) with the [Wand](http://dahlia.kr/wand/) python bindings. Or the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Comment: Thanks so much.But I need to ask >Can I install GIMP as a library or a package may be rather than the GIMP itself with its user interface and all other stuff?

Comment: GIMP includes a library, `libgimp`. Some linux distributions seem to install libgimp as a seperate package, so I'd guess it is possible.

Comment: mmmm So if `libgimp` is only installed, I can import the functions of this library and use them .right!?? sorry I just get confused.If so, that will be amazing for me.Thanks again

Comment: Libgimp _and_ the python bindings.

Comment: Thanks,you are helping me a lot in here Ronald.So I need your opinion again > Do you think [GIMP-Python](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/) does the job? or I'm getting confused again ?

Comment: It certainly looks that way. But it has big dependancies like pyGTK and thus the GTK toolkit.

Comment: +1 You are the man Ronald.I'm going to test it.I think it's ok as I'm going to build my GUI using pyGTK anyway.right?

Comment: Ronald.You may want to check my updated post.As we both got confused with `libgimp` abilities.Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Problem solved using the `PythonMagick` .Thanks for mentioning `ImageMagic`.